# Finding Sink in a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

A sink in a directed graph is a vertex i such that there is an edge from every vertex j ≠ i to i and there is no edge from i to any other vertex. A directed graph G with n vertices is represented by its adjacency matrix A, where A[i] [j] = 1 if there is an edge directed from vertex i to j and 0 otherwise. The following algorithm determines whether there is a sink in the graph G.

```html
i = 0
do {
    j = i + 1;
    while ((j < n) && E1) j++;
    if (j < n) E2;
} while (j < n);

flag = 1;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    if ((j! = i) && E3)
        flag = 0;

if (flag)
    printf("Sink exists");
else
    printf("Sink does not exist");
Choose the correct expressions for E3
```

(A) (A[i][j] && !A[j][i])

(B) (!A[i][j] && A[j][i])

(C) (!A[i][j] | |  A[j][i])

(D) (A[i][j] | | !A[j][i])

===========================================================================

> Correct answer is (D)

Comment: Sorry, but I missed what your question was. Could you clarify what you're asking? Also, the code you put in a JavaScript snippet doesn't appear to be valid JavaScript.

Comment: The correct value of E1 and E2.